# Replace a string with a file by VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I would like to search a Word document for a specific string and replace this string with a file using VBA.

So far I got the following (non working code):

```
With doc.Selection.Find
    .text = "[DocA]"
    .Replacement.text = "test"
    .Forward = True
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With

doc.Selection.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject ClassType:="AcroExch.Document.11", _
    filename:= _
    "C:\Users\user\Appendix_A.pdf" _
    , LinkToFile:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=True, IconFileName:= _
    "C:\WINDOWS\Installer\{AC76BA86-7AD7-1033-7B44-AB0000000001}\PDFFile_8.ico" _
    , IconIndex:=0, IconLabel:= _
    "BESCHREIBUNG"
```

Answer (score 0):

1. get rid of your .Replacement

   2. When using .Find, always .ClearFormatting first
   3. Don't forget to .Execute, else nothing is done!
   4. Always check whether anything has been .Found at all

This here should do it, beware: only replaces the very first instance (additions with spacing before & after for distinction):

```
With doc.Selection.Find

    .ClearFormatting

    .Text = "[DocA]"
    .Forward = True
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False

    .Execute

    If .Found Then

        doc.Selection.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject ClassType:="AcroExch.Document.11", _
            FileName:= _
            "C:\Users\user\Appendix_A.pdf" _
            , LinkToFile:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=True, IconFileName:= _
            "C:\WINDOWS\Installer\{AC76BA86-7AD7-1033-7B44-AB0000000001}\PDFFile_8.ico" _
            , IconIndex:=0, IconLabel:= _
            "BESCHREIBUNG"

    End If

End With
```

Comment: Thanks Alot. For some reason this is not working but I cant see why.

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Please specify your error and the line that causes it.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Range object for your find, not the Selection object.  I'm assuming that doc isn't declared as a Document (because you'd get an error 438 - "Object doesn't support this property or method) on this line of code:

```
With doc.Selection.Find
```

So, first things first - use the Selection to grab a range to use.  If doc ***is*** a Document object and you need to get a selection from it, use ActiveWindow:

```
Dim search As Range
Set search = ActiveWindow.Selection.Range
search.Find.ClearFormatting
search.Find.Execute "[DocA]"

If search.Find.Found Then
    search.Text = vbNullString
    search.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject ClassType:="AcroExch.Document.11", _
        FileName:="C:\Users\user\Appendix_A.pdf", LinkToFile:=False, _
        DisplayAsIcon:=True, _
        IconFileName:="C:\WINDOWS\Installer\{AC76BA86-7AD7-1033-7B44-AB0000000001}\PDFFile_8.ico", _
        IconIndex:=0, IconLabel:="BESCHREIBUNG"
End If
```

That will get you exactly one replacement.  If it doesn't, you'll need to check to see if your ClassType is correct, the document exists at the path and filename specified in the FileName parameter, and that the icon exists at the path and filename given in the IconFileName parameter.

Also remember that you appear to want to work with the Selection, so the find operation will only look in the selected text.  If you want to search the entire document, replace this...

```
Set search = ActiveWindow.Selection.Range
```

...with this:

```
Set search = ActiveDocument.Range
```